# How can I connect an existing app in the AWS Amplify Console with the AWS Amplify CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

As described here I can host my app in AWS Amplify console from AWS Amplify CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/host-your-apps-with-aws-amplify-console-from-the-aws-amplify-cli/

Is it also possible to connect an existing app to the CLI? When I try to it with `amplify add hosting` I get this message: "You have already connected branches to your Amplify Console app. Please visit the Amplify Console to manage your branches"

My goal is to have the status of the hosted app also in the CLI.

Comment: Delete the amplify folder and run amplify pull using corrected app id

Answer (score 1):

I managed it by deleting my app in the amplify console and recreating the hosting via the amplify CLI.
The following error was displayed:

```
App <<appid>> not found.
```

But after I created a new amplify envirmoment `amplify add hosting` worked.

Comment: Maybe it could be also solved if "AmplifyAppId" been deleted inteam-provider-info.json and then `amplify add hosting` again.